# How to add something on an image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an anatomic picture and on it, I want to print a image like a dot or something when the user taps on the first image (the body) to point out where does it hurts.

I've already read something on UITapGestureRecognizer, but I don't really understood how it works.

Comment: Consider using UIBezierPath and CALayer to draw the dot wherever the user touch using touch delegates like touches began, touch moved and touch end. Now don't ask for the code for this as anybody who answers it will have to write a whole blog on that.

Comment: Why don't you try some of the things that you've read, and then come back here with some code if you can't make it work.
You can start with something like [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleTap))
    self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func handleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let circle = UIView()
    circle.center = tap.locationInView(imageView)
    circle.frame.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    circle.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    imageView.addSubview(circle)
}
```